# Apache cordova ,Unable to create an app

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, npm

This is the output , knowing that i'm running it under a proxy , and i specified the proxy settings.

```
 npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
 npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

then i run this command to create a new app in the specified folder "hello".

```
 C:\>cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
 Creating a new cordova project with name "HelloWorld" and id "com.example.hello"
 at location "C:\hello"
 Downloading cordova library for www...
```

this is the error :

```
  Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
```

Comment: there are people who help , and there are others who just try to judge people. i'm waiting for an answer and you are down voting me , take them all if you want. i'm not here for reputation i'm here to help and get answers

Comment: Where/how did you specify the proxy settings?

Comment: @MBillau npm config set proxy http://proxy.*******.com:8080

npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.*******.com:8080

Comment: Can you also try to set the git proxy as well?

Comment: i run the cmd.exe as administrator , it works just fine. So thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after digging a little bit more. i found the solution.

I have just run the cmd.exe as administrator. after that worked like magic.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same issue. I was maintaining an existing app and updating Cordova was well beyond the scope of the current task, so getting this working was really my only option.

Firstly, in order to eliminate all the errors and warnings about deprecated APIs when installing Cordova, I had to use some really ancient package managers. Using NVM I installed node 0.10.48 and npm 1.4.29. Cordova 3.6.3 then installed without any complaints.

But even creating an empty Cordova project wasn't possible as the below output shows:

```
Creating a new cordova project with name "HelloWorld" and id "com.example.hello" at location "~/Downloads"
Downloading cordova library for www...
Error: HTTP error 404 retrieving version 3.6.3 of cordova for www
    at Request._callback (~/.nvm/v0.10.48/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/lazy_load.js:230:30)
    at Request.self.callback (~/.nvm/v0.10.48/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/request/index.js:148:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Request.<anonymous> (~/.nvm/v0.10.48/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/request/index.js:886:14)
    at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (~/.nvm/v0.10.48/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/request/index.js:837:12)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:944:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:458:13)
```

Adding some extra debug output to lazy_load.js revealed that the CLI was looking for a directory at ~/.cordova/lib/www/cordova/3.6.3.

Since this was a brand new installation of Cordova, that directory obviously wasn't present so it went to download an archive from https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-app-hello-world.git;a=snapshot;h=3.6.3;sf=tgz but the archive that used to be there has apparently been removed. I found it at https://github.com/apache/cordova-app-hello-world/releases/tag/3.6.3.

I download that archive and extracted it to ~/.cordova/lib/www/cordova/3.6.3, and I was then able to create my template app.

I know this thread is old but I really hope this helps someone. Working with Cordova is a bitch at the best of times, let alone when vital online components are removed like this.

Comment: This workds, thanks. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

On OSX Yosemite even with sudo the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem by *not* installing cordova as admin. I had to `sudo npm install -g cordova` to get the `create` command to work.